# How to show in practice that a procedure for testing joint hypothesis is conservative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, bonferroni

Consider three random variables $A,B,C$ and suppose I want to test
$$
H_0: A\perp B \text{ and } A\perp C \text{ and } B\perp C
$$
at $\alpha \%$ level.

One way to proceed is to test 
$$
H^1_0: A\perp B
$$
at $\frac{\alpha}{3} \%$ level.
$$
H^2_0: A\perp C
$$
at $\frac{\alpha}{3} \%$ level.
$$
H^3_0: B\perp C
$$
at $\frac{\alpha}{3} \%$ level (also called Bonferroni correction) and reject $H_0$ if at least one among $H_0^1, H_0^2, H_0^3$ is rejected.

As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) the Bonferroni correction can be conservative. In the example highlighted above, how can I show such a conservativeness in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems hard to "show in practice" in the sense of showing a mathematical result in that you do know not if the null is true or false (that is why you test in the first place), so a non-rejection could be either a correct outcome or a type-II error.

That said, you can maybe gather some evidence for the conservativeness of Bonferroni if you use a correction that is less conservative while still controlling the familywise error rate. An easy alternative is given by the Holm procedure.

EDIT:

An illustration (here, only a single round of a potential MC simulation) with artificial data might look like this:

```
library(MASS)
k <- 20
n <- 100

x <- mvrnorm(n,mu=rep(.1,k), Sigma = diag(k)) # k normal vectors with a nonzero mean, so null of t.test below is false

tests <- apply(x, 2, t.test)
p.values <- unlist(sapply(tests, function(x) x[3]))
any(p.values < 0.05/k) # Bonferroni cutoff
any(p.values < 0.05)   # "standard" cutoff ignoring multiple testing
```

This will reveal that it will occur much less frequently that the smallest p-value is less than the Bonferroni cutoff $\alpha/k$ than that it is smaller than the "default" cutoff of $\alpha$. Of course, the latter strategy will not control the FWER, so this would not be an appropriate thing to do when multiple testing issues are a relevant concern.

Comment: Many thanks. Regarding "showing in practice", I was wondering whether, maybe, a specific Monte Carlo exercise could help..

Comment: OK, I tried an edit.